# Server Error in '/' Application. connection database

Tags: visual-studio

please help me
is SYNTAX ERROR? or... database problem?

I can't find the problem

[[image: Error]]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet so users will have a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: hard to read, but can say that, your application try to connect to database, but access is denied. Check your connection string

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I didn't write clearly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class account_login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Server=163.17.9.63;Database=DB1_xx;User Id=DB1_xx;Password=DB1_xx; ");
        Conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From db_account Where account='" + account.Text + "' and password = '" + password.Text + "'", Conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (!dr.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = "error!";
            cmd.Cancel();
            dr.Close();
            Conn.Close();
            Conn.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Login"] = "OK";
            Session["name"] = dr["name"].ToString();
            Session["rank"] = dr["rank"].ToString();
            cmd.Cancel();
            dr.Close();
            Conn.Close();
            Conn.Dispose();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('success!!!');location.href='../main.aspx'</script>");
        }
    }
}
```